# AngularJS - AUTO module and $injector

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, autowired, callstack

On [this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO), the Angular docs describe the `AUTO` module as:

```
Implicit module which gets automatically added to each $injector.
```

Yet, the `$injector` is located inside this `AUTO` module.

```
AUTO
    $injector
        AUTO
            $injector ...
```

Clearly I'm missing something.

How does the `AUTO` module relate to the `angular.module()`, and where does the `$injector` fit in?

```
angular.module()
    AUTO
        $injector
```

This would make sense, but then the docs that imply that `AUTO` is added to `$injector` doesn't make sense.  I'm wondering if I'm misinterpreting something.  So my question is, am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I'm missing a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AUTO basically wires up modules with $provide and $injector. The $injector references itself so $injector === $injector.get('$injector'). It avoids the chicken/egg scenario by building up the module outside of the Angular context and manually shoving the $injector and $provide into it. From that point forward the module can then use $provide, $injector, etc. You will never reference a module explicitly called "AUTO" but any module you create via angular.module will have an $injector and $provide. The other services come from the 'ng' module but the AUTO portion of it has to be built up so there is a DI container to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two injectors, an internal one, and an external one:

> The instanceInjector stores the list of instantiated services in the system. It is initialized with an empty object. The providerInjector maintains the list of uninstantiated services.

The `angular.injector` method can create an instance:

```
angular.injector().get("$injector")
```

The built-in module `ng` can also:

```
angular.module("ng")._configBlocks[0][0]
```

**References**

- [Studying the Angular injector - the twin injectors](http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-the-twin-injectors/)
- [Deconstructing AngularJS Injector](http://neverfriday.com/2013/11/30/deconstructing-angularjs-injector/)
- [AngularJS Error Reference: $injector - cdep](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep)
- [AngularJS source: injectorSpec.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/test/auto/injectorSpec.js)